# validation alert message for zip code

Tags: javascript

Hi I am not getting my alert message correctly and my code is:

```
function isNumberKey( event ) {
    var charCode = (event.which)? event.which: event.keyCode;
    var ctrl = event.ctrlKey;
    var shift1=event.shiftKey;
    var zipcode=document.getElementById(zipCode).value;

    if ( ctrl ) {
       return true;
    }
    if ( ( charCode >= 95 && charCode <= 105) || (charCode >= 106 && charCode <= 123 ) ) {
       return true;
    }
    if ( charCode == 36 || charCode == 35 || charCode == 45 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 144 || charCode == 145 ) {
       return true;
    }
    if ( charCode >= 106 && charCode <= 123 ) {
       return true;
    }
    if ( ( shift1 ) || charCode > 41 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 ) ) {
   alert("The ZIP Code entered is invalid. Please enter a 5 digit ZIP Code.");
       return true;
    }   
}
```

can anyone help for this ?

Comment: What you are trying to check here ? Developer your program readability bu inserting proper comments so that we can understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might missed to add quotes

```
var zipcode=document.getElementById('zipCode').value;  //MISSED '
```

**Updates:**

Rather simplify your code like below

```
<input type='text' maxlength='5' id='zipCode' onkeypress='isNumberKey(this)' />
```

**JS:**

```
function isNumberKey(event) {
    event.value = event.value.replace(/[^\d]/ig, "");
}
```

Check in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmpGz/2/)

Comment: still it not display proper message and display message like:The ZIP Code entered is invalid. Please enter a ZIP Code again.

Comment: Seems that your code needs to be carved, let me try it in jsfiddle